# What is a Fade Word™?

Tags: knowledge, pattern, computer-puzzle, word-property

<sub>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sub>

---

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Fade Word™.
Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| Fade Words™ | Not Fade Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| WHITE | BLACK |
| ORANGE | PLUM |
| SALMON | TEAL |
| TOMATO | OLIVE |
| LAVENDER | ORCHID |
| WHEAT | CHOCOLATE |
| THISTLE | VIOLET |
| SEASHELL | NAVY |
| GOLD | SILVER |
| LINEN | SIENNA |

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Fade Words™,Not Fade Words™
WHITE,BLACK
ORANGE,PLUM
SALMON,TEAL
TOMATO,OLIVE
LAVENDER,ORCHID
WHEAT,CHOCOLATE
THISTLE,VIOLET
SEASHELL,NAVY
GOLD,SILVER
LINEN,SIENNA
```

Hint 1:

> **F**ADE

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A Fade Word™ is

> An X11 color name with an F anywhere in its three hex values

As shown by

> [image]

Incidentally

> Many of the words also happen to align with the rule that their R, G, and B values are in descending order, but not all of them

Comment: You've identified the "F"ade colors :P